# Magento 1 how to get radio button value at payment method?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

I have a custom payment with custom block and added two radio buttons

```
        <li>
            <input type="radio" name=payment["opts"] value="global" checked>
            <label for="1">option 1</label>
        </li>
        <li>            
            <input type="radio" name=payment["opts"] value="local">
            <label for="2">option 2</label>
        </li>
```

but how do I get the **options value** inside the controller or block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this to get the value of checked option value and you can use this value in **Ajax Request** to send it to the controller.

```
$('input[name=opts]:checked').val();
```

Comment: i solved this question by using info block, reference module is here https://github.com/tri-edge/CustomPaymentMethodMagento, finally i can get the options value by $order->getPayment()->getOpts()